# How to find the values that have changed in a form submission?

Tags: forms

How can I tell what values have changed in a validate hook of a form submission?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I have done is to see if the value in `$form_state['values']` is different from the `#default_value` in `$form`, like so:

```
if ( $form_state['values']['variable'] <> $form['variable']['#default_value'] ) { ... }
```

Comment: kinda what i said above, no?

Comment: Couldn't tell -- it seemed like only a flag to indicate that a change had occurred? I wanted more granularity.

Answer (score 4):

Something that i do in my forms is set defaults.

Take:

```
    isset($form_state['values']['datacenter']) ?
    $selected = $form_state['values']['datacenter'] : $selected = 0;

$form['grid']['datacenter'] = array(
    '#title'            => 'Datacenter',
    '#type'             => 'radios',
    '#default_value'    => $selected,
    '#required'         => true,
    '#options'          => array(),                     
);
```

what you could do is check your `#default_value` to see if its not 0 in this case. so in your `MYMODULE_form_validate($form, &$form_state)` function, simply grab your `$form_state` values and if its not zero in this case, call some other function or whatever you want to do.